# Show data for only specific id in laravel-8

Tags: laravel-8, laravel-excel

This is error now:
[image]

This is my post
[image]
suppose I have two id 1 & 2 if ca click id 1 it will take me to index.blade.php where i can upload new data. like data_1 and data_2 those data will show on index.blade.php

And if I click id 2 it will take me to index.blade.php where i don`t want to see data of id 1 as i uploaded data1 and data2.

If I upload new data for id 2 I can see those data in index.blde.php

This is ProjectController.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Exports\UsersExport;
use App\Models\Project;
use App\Imports\ProjectsImport;
use App\Models\Product;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Facades\Excel;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class ProjectController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    // public function index()
    // {
    //     $product = Project::whereIn('product_id',Product::where('user_id',Auth::id())->pluck('id')->toArray())->latest()->paginate(20);
    //     $projects = Project::where('product_id',$product)->latest()->paginate(20);

    //     return view('projects.index', compact('projects'))
    //         ->with('i', (request()->input('page', 1) - 1) * 5);
    // }

    // public function productProjects($product_id)
    // {
    //     $product = Product::where('user_id', Auth::id())->where('id', $product_id)->firstOrFail();
    //     $projects = Project::where('product_id', $product->id)->latest()->paginate(20);

    //     return view('projects.index', compact('projects'))
    //         ->with('i', (request()->input('page', 1) - 1) * 5);
    // }

    public function index($product_id)
    {
        $product = Product::where('user_id', Auth::id())->where('id', $product_id)->firstOrFail();
        $projects = Project::where('product_id', $product->id)->latest()->paginate(20);

        return view('projects.index', compact('projects'))
            ->with('i', (request()->input('page', 1) - 1) * 5);
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function create()
    {
        return view('projects.create');
    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $request->validate([
            'chapter_name' => 'required',
            'sub_section_name' => 'required',
            'title_1' => 'required',
            'description_1' => 'required',
            'image_1' => 'required',
            'image_2' => 'required',
            'image_3' => 'required',
            'title_2' => 'required',
            'description_2' => 'required',
            'title_3' => 'required',
            'description_3' => 'required',
            'video_1' => 'required',
            'video_2' => 'required',
            'video_3' => 'required',
        ]);

        // $input = $request->all();
        // $input['user_id'] = auth()->user()->id;
        // $input['product_id'] = $id;
        $input = Project::whereIn('product_id',Product::where('user_id',Auth::id())->pluck('id'));


        Project::create($input);

        return redirect()->route('project.index')
                        ->with('success','Product created successfully.');

    }

    /**
     * Display the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  \App\Models\Project  $project
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    // public function show(Project $project)
    // {
    //     return view('projects.show', compact('project'));
    // }

    public function show(Product $product)
{
    return view('projects.show', [
        'projects' => $product->projects()->latest()->paginate(20),
    ]);
}

    /**
     * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  \App\Models\Project  $project
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function edit(Project $project)
    {
        return view('projects.edit', compact('project'));
    }
    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \App\Models\Project  $project
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function update(Request $request, Project $project)
    {
        // $user_id =  Auth::user()->id ;

        $request->validate([
            'chapter_name' => 'required',
            'sub_section_name' => 'required',
            'title_1' => 'required',
            'description_1' => 'required',
            'image_1' => 'required',
            'image_2' => 'required',
            'image_3' => 'required',
            'title_2' => 'required',
            'description_2' => 'required',
            'title_3' => 'required',
            'description_3' => 'required',
            'video_1' => 'required',
            'video_2' => 'required',
            'video_3' => 'required',
        ]);

        $input = $request->all();

        $project->update($input);

        return redirect()->route('project.index')
                        ->with('success','Product updated successfully');
    }
    /**
     * Remove the specified resource from storage.
     *
     * @param  \App\Models\Project  $project
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function destroy(Project $project)
    {
        $project->delete();

        return redirect()->route('projects.index')
            ->with('success', 'Project deleted successfully');
    }

    public function importProject()
    {
        Excel::import(new ProjectsImport, request()->file('file'));

        return back()->with('success','Project created successfully.');
    }

    public function export()
    {
        return Excel::download(new UsersExport, 'projects.xlsx');
    }
}
```

This is index.blade.php

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12 margin-tb">
            <div class="pull-left">
                <h2>Laravel 8 CRUD </h2>
            </div>
            <div class="d-flex flex-row-reverse flex-column">
                <div class="d-flex">
                    <a class="btn btn-success text-light mr-5" data-toggle="medel" id="mediumButton" data-target="#mediumModel"
                    data-attr="{{ route ('projects.create')}}" title="upload project">
                        <i class="fas fa-cloud-upload-alt fa-2x"></i>
                    </a>

                    <a href="{{ route('projects.index', ['product_id' => $product_id]) }}">See Projects</a>


                    <form action="{{ route('importProject') }}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="d-flex">
                        @csrf
                        <input type='file' name="file">

                        <button class="btn btn-info" style="margin-left: -60px" title="Import Project">
                            <i class="fas fa-cloud-upload-alt fa-2x"></i></button>

                            <a class="btn btn-warning" href="{{ route('export') }}">Export User Data</a>
                    </form>

                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="pull-right">
                <a class="btn btn-success text-light" data-toggle="modal" id="mediumButton" data-target="#mediumModal"
                    data-attr="{{ route('projects.create') }}" title="Create a project"> <i class="fas fa-plus-circle"></i>
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    @if ($message = Session::get('success'))
        <div class="alert alert-success">
            <p>{{ $message }}</p>
        </div>
    @endif

    <table class="table table-bordered table-responsive-lg table-hover">
        <thead class="thead-dark">
            <tr>
                <th scope="col">No</th>
                <th scope="col">Chapter Name</th>
                <th scope="col" >Sub-Section Name</th>
                <th scope="col">Title 1</th>
                <th scope="col">Description 1</th>
                <th scope="col">Image 1</th>
                <th scope="col">Image 2</th>
                <th scope="col">Image 3</th>
                <th scope="col">Title 2</th>
                <th scope="col">Description 2</th>
                <th scope="col">Title 3</th>
                <th scope="col">Description 3</th>
                <th scope="col">Video 1</th>
                <th scope="col">Video 2</th>
                <th scope="col">Video 3</th>

                <th scope="col">Date Created</th>
                <th scope="col">Action</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @foreach ($projects as $project)
                <tr>
                    <td scope="row">{{ ++$i }}</td>
                    <td>{{ $project->chapter_name }}</td>
                    <td>{{ $project->sub_section_name }}</td>
                    <td>{{ $project->title_1 }}</td>
                    <td>{{ $project->description_1 }}</td>
                    <td>{{ $project->image_1 }}</td>
                    <td>{{ $project->image_2 }}</td>
                    <td>{{ $project->image_3 }}</td>
                    <td>{{ $project->title_2 }}</td>
                    <td>{{ $project->description_2 }}</td>
                    <td>{{ $project->title_3 }}</td>
                    <td>{{ $project->description_3 }}</td>
                    <td>{{ $project->video_1 }}</td>
                    <td>{{ $project->video_2 }}</td>
                    <td>{{ $project->video_3 }}</td>

                    <td>{{ date_format($project->created_at, 'jS M Y') }}</td>
                    <td>
                        <form action="{{ route('projects.destroy', $project->id) }}" method="POST">

                            <a data-toggle="modal" id="smallButton" data-target="#smallModal"
                                data-attr="{{ route('projects.show', $project->id) }}" title="show">
                                <i class="fas fa-eye text-success  fa-lg"></i>
                            </a>

                            <a class="text-secondary" data-toggle="modal" id="mediumButton" data-target="#mediumModal"
                                data-attr="{{ route('projects.edit', $project->id) }}">
                                <i class="fas fa-edit text-gray-300"></i>
                            </a>
                            @csrf
                            @method('DELETE')

                            <button type="submit" title="delete" style="border: none; background-color:transparent;">
                                <i class="fas fa-trash fa-lg text-danger"></i>
                            </button>
                        </form>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            @endforeach
        </tbody>
    </table>

    {!! $projects->links() !!}


    <!-- small modal -->
    <div class="modal fade" id="smallModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="smallModalLabel"
        aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body" id="smallBody">
                    <div>
                        <!-- the result to be displayed apply here -->
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>


    <!-- medium modal -->
    <div class="modal fade" id="mediumModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="mediumModalLabel"
        aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body" id="mediumBody">
                    <div>
                        <!-- the result to be displayed apply here -->
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>


    <script>
        // display a modal (small modal)
        $(document).on('click', '#smallButton', function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            let href = $(this).attr('data-attr');
            $.ajax({
                url: href,
                beforeSend: function() {
                    $('#loader').show();
                },
                // return the result
                success: function(result) {
                    $('#smallModal').modal("show");
                    $('#smallBody').html(result).show();
                },
                complete: function() {
                    $('#loader').hide();
                },
                error: function(jqXHR, testStatus, error) {
                    console.log(error);
                    alert("Page " + href + " cannot open. Error:" + error);
                    $('#loader').hide();
                },
                timeout: 8000
            })
        });

        // display a modal (medium modal)
        $(document).on('click', '#mediumButton', function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            let href = $(this).attr('data-attr');
            $.ajax({
                url: href,
                beforeSend: function() {
                    $('#loader').show();
                },
                // return the result
                success: function(result) {
                    $('#mediumModal').modal("show");
                    $('#mediumBody').html(result).show();
                },
                complete: function() {
                    $('#loader').hide();
                },
                error: function(jqXHR, testStatus, error) {
                    console.log(error);
                    alert("Page " + href + " cannot open. Error:" + error);
                    $('#loader').hide();
                },
                timeout: 8000
            })
        });

    </script>

@endsection
```

This is my web.php

```
<?php

use App\Http\Controllers\ProductController;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
use App\Http\Controllers\ProjectController;
use App\Http\Controllers\MyController;



/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Web Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register web routes for your application. These
| routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider within a group which
| contains the "web" middleware group. Now create something great!
|
*/

Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});

Route::middleware(['auth:sanctum', 'verified'])->get('/dashboard', function () {
    return view('dashboard');
})->name('dashboard');

Route::resource('products', ProductController::class);

Route::post('projects/importProject', [ProjectController::class, 'importProject'])->name('importProject');

// Route::resource('projects', ProjectController::class);
Route::resource('projects', 'ProjectController', ['parameters' => [
    'index' => 'product_id'
]]);

Route::get('export', [MyController::class, 'export'])->name('export');
```

This is RouteServiceProvidor.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Cache\RateLimiting\Limit;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Support\Providers\RouteServiceProvider as ServiceProvider;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\RateLimiter;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

class RouteServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * The path to the "home" route for your application.
     *
     * This is used by Laravel authentication to redirect users after login.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    public const HOME = '/products';

    /**
     * The controller namespace for the application.
     *
     * When present, controller route declarations will automatically be prefixed with this namespace.
     *
     * @var string|null
     */
    // protected $namespace = 'App\\Http\\Controllers';

    /**
     * Define your route model bindings, pattern filters, etc.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    // public function boot()
    // {
    //     $this->configureRateLimiting();

    //     $this->routes(function () {
    //         Route::prefix('api')
    //             ->middleware('api')
    //             ->namespace($this->namespace)
    //             ->group(base_path('routes/api.php'));

    //         Route::middleware('web')
    //             ->namespace($this->namespace)
    //             ->group(base_path('routes/web.php'));
    //     });
    // }

    public function boot()
    {
        $this->configureRateLimiting();

        $this->routes(function () {
            Route::prefix('api')
                ->middleware('api')
                ->namespace($this->namespace)
                ->group(base_path('routes/api.php'));

            Route::middleware('web')
                ->namespace('App\Http\Controllers') // <<<- Here is the change
                ->group(base_path('routes/web.php'));
        });
    }

    /**
     * Configure the rate limiters for the application.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    protected function configureRateLimiting()
    {
        RateLimiter::for('api', function (Request $request) {
            return Limit::perMinute(60)->by(optional($request->user())->id ?: $request->ip());
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: I didn't get "but is showing all data of user_id". Please explain more and tell your desired result with an example

Comment: supose i have user with id 1 in user table lets call id user1. user1 can create many products supose user1 create product1, product2 and product3. Now user1 can create many projects inside all of the products. supose user1 create project1 and project2 inside product1 and show it on view. The user1 goto inside products2 for create some new projects but befor create any projects inside product2 in view here showing project1 and project2 which shouldn`t be show here. inside product2 view sould be empty. When user1 create project inside product2 then projects under product2 will show in view

Comment: You can see i have edit my post

Answer (score 0):

It's because you get all projects of specific user at one time. You need to specify which product projects you want. You have to do this with product id.

In ProjectController.php:

```
public function index($product_id)
    {
        $product = Product::where('user_id', Auth::id())->where('id', $product_id)->firstOrFail();
        $projects = Project::where('product_id', $product->id))->latest()->paginate(20);

        return view('projects.index', compact('projects'))
            ->with('i', (request()->input('page', 1) - 1) * 5);
    }
```

And in your `web.php`:

```
Route::resource('projects', 'ProjectController', ['parameters' => [
    'index' => 'product_id'
]]);
```

Notice that you should define controllers namespace in `RouteServiceProvider.php` like this:

```
public function boot()
    {
        $this->configureRateLimiting();

        $this->routes(function () {
            Route::prefix('api')
                ->middleware('api')
                ->namespace($this->namespace)
                ->group(base_path('routes/api.php'));

            Route::middleware('web')
                ->namespace('App\Http\Controllers') // <<<- Here is the change
                ->group(base_path('routes/web.php'));
        });
    }
```

Then you can use this route with name in your view, like this:

```
 <a href="{{ route('projects.index', ['product_id' => $product_id]) }}">See Projects</a>
```

Comment: I Can`t declar product_id as variable they show me this error
Too few arguments to function App\Http\Controllers\ProjectController::index(), 0 passed in C:\xampp\htdocs\ContentBaseApp\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Controller.php on line 54 and exactly 1 expected.

Comment: Because I think you set one parameter for ```index``` method and you don't pass that parameter to the method. I updated the answer and added route for this ```productProjects``` method.

Comment: What change should I make in my index() method ?
``` public function index()
    {
        $projects = Project::whereIn('product_id',Product::where('user_id',Auth::id())->pluck('id')->toArray())->latest()->paginate(20);


        return view('projects.index', compact('projects'))
            ->with('i', (request()->input('page', 1) - 1) * 5);
    }````

Comment: Please can you see my ProjectController and web.php again I have edit my post

Comment: @AbdullahAlShahed In index method it returns all user's projects as you see. But in new method that I write ```productProjects``` you can get only projects of a special product. What's your difficulty?It's not working?

Comment: Undefined variable $product_id (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\ContentBaseApp\resources\views\projects\index.blade.php) Now this error is showing

Comment: Brother I want index method will return only projects of special product.  I don`t want to user my present index.

Comment: Can you please help me out of this error : Undefined variable $product_id (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\ContentBaseApp\resources\views\projects\index.blade.php)

Comment: @AbdullahAlShahed Its because you use ```resource``` for your route and the default route for index has no parameter. If you want to send some parameter for index like ```$product_id``` parameter you should define that. I have updated my answer.

Comment: Target class [App\Http\Controllers\App\Http\Controllers\ProductController] does not exist.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233724/discussion-between-mohammad-hosseini-and-abdullah-al-shahed).